# API returns Must declare the scalar variable error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using the Entity Framework Core and trying to execute the query which has two filter parameters and get the response back. I am calling my API from the Angular Application.

[image]

Above both can be passed as a query to the EF Core  or the users might select only one field then accordingly the filter should change

What I am doing is like below

```
    public List<ShipmentDetailByShipDate> GetByQueryFilter(string queryPara)
    {
        var queryParameter = new SqlParameter("queryPara", queryPara);
        return _context.ShipmentDetailsByShipDate.FromSql<ShipmentDetailByShipDate>(SQueryPara, queryParameter).ToList();
    }
```

Where the string `SQuerPara` holds the query

```
        SQueryPara = @"Select prj_number,location from sTable where @queryParameter group by prj_number,location";
```

My Controller method is like

```
    public IActionResult GetByQueryFilter()
    {
        string queryPara = "r_proj = '000634' and sdate = '2019-07-01'";
        return Ok(_shipmentRepository.GetByQueryFilter(queryPara));
    }
```

For testing purpose I am hardcoding the `queryPara` with in the Controller. But when I call my API I am getting the error like 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@queryParameter".'`

How can I handle this scenario, can this be handled differently?

Comment: `@queryPara` != `@queryParameter`

Comment: Ok. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"@queryPara" != "@queryParameter";
```

You pass `"queryPara"` as the name in the parameter

```
var queryParameter = new SqlParameter("queryPara", queryPara);
```

but use `@queryParameter` in the statement

```
"...where @queryParameter group by..."
```

The names given to `SqlParameter` needs to match ones used is statements.

```
var queryParameter = new SqlParameter("queryParameter", queryPara);
```

But given that you are passing something like

```
string queryPara = "r_proj = '000634' and sdate = '2019-07-01'"
```

into the query, this will give you the following

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

because the statement is not being constructed properly.

Consider refactoring the approach used.

Construct a proper parameterized statement to avoid SQL injection attacks

```
public List<ShipmentDetailByShipDate> GetByQueryFilter(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters = null) {
    if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0) {        
        return _context.ShipmentDetailsByShipDate.FromSql<ShipmentDetailByShipDate>(query, parameters).ToList();
    }

    return return _context.ShipmentDetailsByShipDate.FromSql<ShipmentDetailByShipDate>(query).ToList();
}
```

and construct your filter accordingly.

```
public IActionResult GetByQueryFilter() {
    string query = @"Select prj_number,location from sTable where r_proj = @r_proj and sdate = @sdate group by prj_number,location";
    var parameters = new [] {
        new SqlParameter("r_proj", "000634"),
        new SqlParameter("sdate", "2019-07-01"),
    }
    return Ok(_shipmentRepository.GetByQueryFilter(query, parameters));
}
```

Comment: I get now `: 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'group'.'`

Comment: @trx You can't pass an expression as a parameter. One of the reasons for using parameters is to prevent exactly this. At the moment your resultant SQL is effectively `Select prj_number,location from sTable where 'r_proj = ''000634'' and sdate = ''2019-07-01''' group by prj_number,location`, which doesn't make any sense. You should pass `r_proj` and `sdate` as separate parameters and reference them in your query as `where r_proj = @rproj AND sdate = @sdate`.

Comment: @John yep realized that as soon as answer was accepted and comment made, but couldn't delete because of the accept so I can edit.